# How can only enter record in journey only when status field value change?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

-We created a Data extension to fetch records from the publication list

-Created a journey to update the contact checkbox field based on the status value

-We used automation to run the journey every hour

-Contact Evaluation: The journey will evaluate all new records.
-Journey On re-entry anytime mode

-We want to enter the record only when the status field value changes

Now all records entering again and again if the status not changes

How can do it? Please help me with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of working with a single data extension, you should work with three separate ones.

1. Import DE - here you will be able to overwrite your records with latest version on them from publication list
2. Archive DE - this you will use for comparing your import DE with previous "version" of your records. By selecting records where status field differs between Import and Archive DE you will be able to find the records you need.
3. Journey DE - here you will add the records found by above comparison. Only these will be injected to your journey.

As one last step, before triggering journey, you will need to update your Archive DE with all records from Import DE, so you have the most recent version accurately represented for all your records.